# Could Apple be blocking my Game Kit requests?

Tags: ios, game-center

I am getting this error when I request a image for the users Game Center Profile picture:

> Failure retrieving player image for player ID G:188370944 with game 
>   center: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation 
>   could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server."

I had it working before. Is it possible that I sent too many requests and that Apple is blocking me from the sandbox dev server?

Answer (score 0):

That error appears when the player doesn't have an image.  Try uploading a player image in Game Center (although it will be replaced by Apple's default image in the sandbox for some reason).